# How to sort the output of `ls`?

Tags: command-line, ls

Is it possible to view this output sorted with titlepage_1.pdf before titlepage_19.pdf?

```
$ ls
allTitlepage.pdf         titlepage_12.pdf  titlepage_19.tex  titlepage_26.pdf  titlepage_32.tex  titlepage_4.tex
allTitlepage.tex         titlepage_12.tex  titlepage_1.pdf   titlepage_26.tex  titlepage_33.pdf  titlepage_5.pdf
assignment.pdf           titlepage_13.pdf  titlepage_1.tex   titlepage_27.pdf  titlepage_34.pdf  titlepage_5.tex
assignment.tex           titlepage_13.tex  titlepage_20.pdf  titlepage_27.tex  titlepage_34.tex  titlepage_6.pdf
graphicsAssignment2.pdf  titlepage_14.pdf  titlepage_20.tex  titlepage_28.pdf  titlepage_35.pdf  titlepage_6.tex
graphicsAssignment2.tex  titlepage_14.tex  titlepage_21.pdf  titlepage_28.tex  titlepage_35.tex  titlepage_7.pdf
README.md                titlepage_15.pdf  titlepage_21.tex  titlepage_29.pdf  titlepage_36.pdf  titlepage_7.tex
thesisTitlepage.pdf      titlepage_15.tex  titlepage_22.pdf  titlepage_29.tex  titlepage_36.tex  titlepage_8.pdf
thesisTitlepage.tex      titlepage_16.pdf  titlepage_22.tex  titlepage_2.pdf   titlepage_37.pdf  titlepage_8.tex
titlepage_0.pdf          titlepage_16.tex  titlepage_23.pdf  titlepage_2.tex   titlepage_37.tex  titlepage_9.pdf
titlepage_0.tex          titlepage_17.pdf  titlepage_23.tex  titlepage_30.pdf  titlepage_38.pdf  titlepage_9.tex
titlepage_10.pdf         titlepage_17.tex  titlepage_24.pdf  titlepage_30.tex  titlepage_38.tex  titlepage_one.pdf
titlepage_10.tex         titlepage_18.pdf  titlepage_24.tex  titlepage_31.pdf  titlepage_3.pdf   titlepage_one.tex
titlepage_11.pdf         titlepage_18.tex  titlepage_25.pdf  titlepage_31.tex  titlepage_3.tex   titlepage_two.tex
titlepage_11.tex         titlepage_19.pdf  titlepage_25.tex  titlepage_32.pdf  titlepage_4.pdf
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the switch -v [natural sort of (version) numbers within text]

```
ls -v
```

If you want single column use

```
ls -1v
```

Answer (score 14):

The output is sorted.  According to the `ls` manpage:

> Sort entries alphabetically if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort is
>          specified.

But if you want to go further, you have at least two options:

**Option 1 - `ls` sort switches**

`man ls` tells you about a number of switches you can use to sort, specifically, the [ls man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) says:

> none (-U), size (-S), time (-t), version (-v), extension (-X)

**In your case, you want "version" sort (-v).**  *Be careful, though, since this will also sort anything that has a `blahblah-X.Y.Z-A` arrangement* which may not be entirely what you want.  See also [GNU's explanation of version sort](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html).

**Option 2 - Pipes to sorting commands**

You could use a pipe `|` to send the output to another command, for example the *command* [`sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) which you could use to sort in a number of other ways, as in `ls -1 | sort -n` which is useful if you have numbered files.  The `-1` switch ensures that the output is one-line-per-file.

Equally, you can manipulate the output to aid with sorting by using things like `sed` or `awk`.

There are plenty of ways to answer this sort of* question.  You may find a linux shell tutorial helpful.

*(See what I did there? :-p)

Answer (score 6):

As already pointed out in a comment, the output *is* already sorted, but by characters, not numbers.
You may want to pipe the output of `ls` through `sort` which has a switch to sort by numbers within strings:

```
ls | sort --version-sort
```

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/sort.1.html):

> ```
> -V, --version-sort
>          natural sort of (version) numbers within text
> ```

**Downside:** When we issue `ls` then it outputs the files in a *table* with as many columns as fit on the current screen (just like you showed in your post). But when `ls` notices that its output is redirected to a file or to a pipe (as in `ls | sort`) then `ls` prints the files in just *one* column because it then assumes the output is to be processed line-by-line (aka file-by-file) by some other program (like `sort`). So the **output of `ls | sort -V` will be in one column** instead of in a table with multiple columns. See [@vijay](https://askubuntu.com/users/390884/vijay)'s simple but [perfect answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1081692/504066) for how to avoid that.

Comment: You could also pipe the output to `column`

Answer (score 0):

`ls -l` : lists files of the directory vertically but not in a particular order.

`ls -l | sort -k 3` : `-k 3` would sort the output of the previous command by the 3rd column.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
ls -ltrh --sort=size
```

Sample output

```
$ ls -ltrh --sort=size
total 13M
drwxr-xr-x 1 tayyab.sarfraz 1049089    0 Nov 11 14:26  ZZZZZ3309669667/
drwxr-xr-x 1 tayyab.sarfraz 1049089    0 Nov 11 14:26  ZZZZZ1036987434/
-rw-r--r-- 1 tayyab.sarfraz 1049089  504 Jun 10 17:11  desktop.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 tayyab.sarfraz 1049089 1021 Oct 30 13:02  jZHcYAg3964781410.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 tayyab.sarfraz 1049089 1021 Oct 30 13:02  jZHcYAg3531170004.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 tayyab.sarfraz 1049089 2.0K Oct 18 13:06  ZZZZZ596653076.doc
-rw-r--r-- 1 tayyab.sarfraz 1049089 2.0K Oct 18 13:06  ZZZZZ2113390587.doc
-rw-r--r-- 1 tayyab.sarfraz 1049089 4.0K Oct 26 12:35 '!!!!!3048223661.pem'
```